# Get an empty diagram when plotting multiple graphs in one diagram

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to plot multiple graphs in one diagram by using a for loop. First I calculate my y for every serial number ad the I try to plot it. In the first line of my for loop I want to select differnet x values by saying: just use the x values to the specific serial number from the for loop.

```
x = dataset['mrwSmpVWi']
c = dataset['c']
a = dataset['a']
b = dataset['b']
    
y = (c / (1 + (a) * np.exp(-b*(x))))

for element in dataset.Seriennummer:
    plt.plot(dataset['mrwSmpVWi'].where(dataset["Seriennummer"] == element),y, linewidth = 4)
    plt.title("TEST")
    plt.xlabel('Wind in m/s')
    plt.ylabel('Leistung in kWh')
    plt.xlim(0,25)
    plt.ylim(0,1900)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider using pyplot.subplots from matplotlib. Here's an example based on a small dataframe as this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Tim", "Lisa", "Amy", "Jim", "Tod", "Nancy"],
                   "Age":[20, 40, 50, 25, 80, 30],
                   "Gender":["M", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F"]})
```

Let's say you want to plot everyone's age but have separate graphs for male and female.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(len(genders), 1)
for i in range(len(genders)):
    df_subset = df[df["Gender"] == genders[i]]
    axs[i].bar(df_subset["Name"], df_subset["Age"])
plt.show()
```

You can stack multiple graphs in different ways like columnwise, rowwise or both with axs[row, column].

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works but its the wrong type of digram. Where can I change it to a line diagram?

Comment: Does subplots always give me more diagrams in one graphic/window? In the end I will have 38 serial numbers and I want to plot them in one diagram to see what diefferneces they have

Comment: 1. You may use axs[i].plot or axs[i].hist or any of the numerous methods in the matplotlib library. I would suggest visiting https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/introductory/sample_plots.html and looking up all the different types of graphs you can make.
2. You may plot all 38 diagrams in the same window, just make sure you specify the dimensions of that window. That would be the number of subplots rowwise and the number of subplots columnwise. For 38 you may choose [8, 5] and that would give you 40 subplots windows of which 2 will be left empty.

Answer (score 0):

It worked this way :)

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dataset.groupby("Seriennummer").plot(x="mrwSmpVWi", y="y", ax=ax)
plt.show()
```